# Is the best way to reference these object properties?

Tags: c#

Just wondering if this is the most eloquent way to write this code:

```
var myObj = new Class();
int myId1 = myObj.Id1;
int myId2 = myObj.Id2;
```

Was trying to do it in 2 lines like:

```
int myId1 = new Class().Id1;
int myId2 = new Class().Id2;
```

But I suspect this is more inefficient as instantiating 2 objects instead of 1.

So what is the leanest way to write the above code.

Thanks.

EDIT.

I am trying to write a central bit of code, and chose to write it in a class. I am trying to insulate the application from the details as to how this values are acquired. From a comment below, it would seem that the use of a static class would be most eloquent.

EDIT2:

After thinking about this a little more, I think it is best if I do use a non static approach since I can populate the class properties in the constructor. So therefore I need one "new" and 2 accessor lines of code, so approach 1 seems best.

Comment: These two situations cannot be guaranteed to be the same so your question is starting from a faulty assumption.

Comment: It's presumably *wrong* precisely because it instantiates an extra object (and immediately throws both of them away).

Comment: `Id1` and `Id2` always get the same value no matter what? You could just make them static then and use `Class.Id1` and `Class.Id2` without having to instantiate anything.

Comment: I think the more important question is what are you trying to do? That is, what is the bigger problem you're trying to solve? It's pretty evident that, based on your question, performance shouldn't be your primary concern.

Comment: I understand that the question isn't very clear but why is there so many downvotes?

Comment: @TopinFrassi, thank you for your comment. I may not be the best c# programmer, hence why I ask questions on this very useful site. There are some good comments here, mainly the use of a static class. I am using a class to centralise some functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to assign `myId1` to the default value of `Class().Id1`, and the same with 2, then you can do it your second way.

However, if you want to be assigning those two variables to the values of a manipulated `Class` object, then do it the first way.

Instantiating a whole new object just to get a second default value is wasteful.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After consideration, see EDIT2, I am going with approach 1.